# jQuery Form post doesn't work with IE8

Tags: jquery, post, internet-explorer-8

I try to do something since few days but it still doesn't work. So i want to do  a post request in cross domain with IE8. I need to send multipart data.
  After severals reseach, i did that :

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.id = "myform";
form.action = url;
form.method = "post";
form.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
form.encoding = "multipart/form-data";
form.style.display = "none";

for (var p in properties) {
    var f = document.createElement("input");
    f.type = "text";
    f.name = p;
    f.value = properties[p]; 
    form.appendChild(f);
}

document.body.appendChild(form);

var options = { 
    success : function(data)  { 
            console.log('success :  ' + data);
        },
    error   : function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) { 
            console.log('error : ' + statusText);
        };


    $("#myform").submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
        return false; 
    }); 

    $("#myform").submit();
```

So basically, i use jquery.form to send multipart data in cross domain. With Chrome and FF, it's work perfectly. I received a string json because as application/json doesn't work with IE8 the response has text/html in content-type.

But i don't understand why but with IE the "data" in success is my page html. I tried to understand why but i didn't find out.

```
success :  
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="lib/jquery.form.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="lib/json2.js"></SCRIPT>
<BUTTON id=action1 onclick=local() type=submit>Local - GET</BUTTON><BR><BUTTON id=action2 onclick=remoteG() type=submit>Remote - GET</BUTTON><BR><BUTTON id=action3 onclick=remoteP() type=submit>Remote - POST</BUTTON><BR><INPUT id=mylabel type=text>
<SCRIPT>
        remoteP = function() {

            .....

 </SCRIPT>
<FORM style="DISPLAY: none" id=myform encType=multipart/form-data method ...></FORM>
```

Also, if i do form.submit() at the end except of $("#myform").submit(), it's open a new page with the good content, so it's prove that the request is correctly done, but i don't know how to get it.

I don't know what i can do to make it works so i need your help.

Thanks,

Alexis

Comment: Why are you loading 2 versions of jQuery?

Comment: they're not - one is jquery ui

Comment: you aren't using the plugin correctly. Please check the documentation and examples. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Note however that using the plugin properly still won't work in IE8 due to the fact that jQuery doesn't support CORS requests in IE8, you have to add an extension to gain that support.

Comment: The plugin takes care of the submit and click event for you, all you need to do is apply the plugin to the form after the form is added to the page. However, again, this won't solve your CORS issue.

Comment: @KevinB, ok so the problem is not how i create the form but how i used the plugin.

Comment: No, the problem is that jquery (and IE8) doesn't support what you are trying to do by default. jQuery does CORS requests using XMLHttpRequest, which IE8 doesn't support. IE8 requires the use of a separate object to perform CORS requests.

Comment: @KevinB, but as i said if i don't use ajaxSubmit and directly submit the "form" object, it's open a new page with the response of my request. So i still don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: i just explained what is wrong...

Comment: posting without ajax is a totally different ballgame. It isn't subject to the same-origin policy and doesn't use CORS.

Comment: @KevinB, i know that i have to use XDomainRequest to perform CORS request but i can't use FormData with it. The only way i found to do that is with something like that.

Comment: Sorry, you can't do that in IE8. the only work around is to not use ajax, either by submitting like you've done previously or targeting an iframe.

Comment: @KevinB, yes indeed i heard about the fact to use an iframe but i didn't find an explicit example to understand. I will take a look tomorrow. Thank you :)